# EAS Build creates development build, but the development build does not work using custom dev client

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, ios-simulator, eas

I am using bare workflow in expo with eas-cli version 0.54.1.

I moved my Expo project from managed workflow to bare workflow to use the native module for Google AdMob (GitHub - invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads: React Native Google Mobile Ads enables you to monetize your app with AdMob.).

With such a change, I wanted to use eas build and custom dev clients (instead of expo build). I am able to create a development build using `eas build --profile development`, provision my device, and download the build on my iPhone, but when I open the app, it gives me a blank white screen.

This also happens when I run `expo start --dev-client`. After digging, I thought this would create the custom dev client and then the downloaded development build should work on my phone, but alas, it still gives me a blank white screen.

I ran `expo run:ios --configuration Release` to test if the build works in an iOS simulator, and it does, so I feel unsure why it doesn’t work using the custom dev client and the development build.

For more context, this is my package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.3.8",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "4.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-picker/picker": "2.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.2",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^3.3.5",
    "apollo-link-ws": "^1.0.20",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "expo": "^44.0.0",
    "expo-analytics-segment": "~11.1.2",
    "expo-application": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-blur": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-clipboard": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-contacts": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "~0.8.6",
    "expo-device": "~4.1.0",
    "expo-firebase-recaptcha": "~2.1.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~11.0.3",
    "expo-linking": "~3.0.0",
    "expo-location": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-media-library": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-navigation-bar": "~1.1.1",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.14.0",
    "expo-sharing": "~10.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "expo-store-review": "~5.1.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~1.1.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.11.7",
    "firebase": "8.2.3",
    "graphql": "^15.5.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-doorman": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^7.0.1",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.29.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.11.2",
    "react-native-purchases": "^4.5.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-redash": "^16.2.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-view-shot": "3.1.2",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.15.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4",
    "sentry-expo": "^4.0.0",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@types/react": "~17.0.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "~17.0.9",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.64.12",
    "eslint-config-nando": "^1.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas!

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: did you find any solution @Vaibhav Verma?